# Why Ant Design CSS looks different on deployment than in development

Tags: css, typescript, next.js, antd

I am currently working on a project where we agreed to use Ant Design library with NextJS and TypeScript
When I test locally using **npm run dev** everything looks alright, but on **npm run build** and **npm run start** the css looks a complete mess.

I tried overriding Ant Design default css using the `!important` property on various of different classes but I don't think that's a very good approach. Has anyone ever encountered such a problem before?
Here is the package.json file if that's relevant

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext js,ts,tsx",
    "test": "jest --config ./configs/jest.config.js",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.7.0",
    "antd": "^4.18.6",
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "next": "^12.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@types/node": "17.0.12",
    "@types/react": "17.0.38",
    "babel-jest": "^27.4.6",
    "concurrently": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint": "8.7.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.8",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-ts-react-important-stuff": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "jest": "^27.4.7",
    "jest-css-modules": "^2.1.0",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your `next.config.js` file?

Comment: /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
};

module.exports = nextConfig;